# Take an array of numbers from standard input in Common Lisp

Tags: arrays, common-lisp

I realise this is a pretty basic question, but I'm just starting out in CL and I was wondering how to take input from standard input like:

1 2 3 4 5

And store it in an array.

I tried this:

```
(setq array (read-line))
```

Then checking the type gives cons.

I also tried constructing an array first like this:

```
(setf array (make-array n :element-type 'number))
```

Where n is the number of values I'll enter as input, but I'm lost after this. Do I need to use a loop or is there a way to do this without one?

Thanks.

Comment: The result of `READ-LINE` is never a cons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do these steps:

- read the line
- split into numbers
- parse the numbers

It could look like this:

```
(defun read-array (stream)
  (let* ((line (read-line stream))
         (items (split-sequence #\Space line))
         (numbers (map 'vector #'parse-integer items)))
    numbers))
```

(`Split-sequence` is from the library of the same name.)

This is just the basic implementation, you likely want to sanitize your input, and split on any run of whitespace.

I advise against using `read` for reading user input, in any way, because the reader can do much more and you need to be very careful with user input.

Comment: Though he wrote 'numbers', not integers. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Your response makes sense, but I have a followup question. I can't seem to call split-sequence. Is there a package I need to use? I tried:
`split-sequence` which gave me an undefined function warning., and used:
`split-sequence:split-sequence` which gave my a Package does not exist error. Thanks!

Comment: @marauder7 It's from a library. You should set up [Quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/)  and do `(ql:quickload :split-sequence)` (in a real project you would add it as a dependency to the projects .asd).

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can you point me to somewhere I can learn more about how dependencies work in CL? I've accepted your answer.

Comment: Parsing numbers (if they can be any kind, but written in Common Lisp syntax) is best done through the `parse-number` library.

Answer (score 1):

The predefined function `read-line` returns a string (see the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_lin.htm#read-line)).

A simple way of obtaining from that string an array (assuming that the numbers are on a single line) is for instance to manipulate the returned string by adding the necessary syntax for reading it as a literal array through the function `read-from-string`. Here is a simple function adapted from one presented for lists in the excellent [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisptext.html) book by Paul Graham:

```
CL-USER> (defun readarray (&rest args)
            (values (read-from-string
                     (concatenate 'string "#("
                                  (apply #'read-line args)
                                  ")"))))
READARRAY
CL-USER> (readarray)
1 2 3 4
#(1 2 3 4)
CL-USER> (type-of *)
(SIMPLE-VECTOR 4)
```

Of course if the numbers are on multiple lines some kind of iteration is required.

Answer (score 1):

One can read from a string, by using a stream. Then one calls `read` as long as there are numbers, collects it into a list and converts the list to a vector.

```
CL-USER 36 > (coerce (with-input-from-string (stream "1 2 3 4 5")
                       (loop for n = (read stream nil nil)
                             while (numberp n)
                             collect n))
                     'vector)
#(1 2 3 4 5)
```

or: one creates a vector, which can grow - in Common Lisp the vector should be adjustable (when the size is unknown) and have a fill pointer. Then read from the string stream and push the numbers onto the vector.

```
CL-USER 40 > (let ((vector (make-array 0 :adjustable t :fill-pointer t)))
               (with-input-from-string (stream "1 2 3 4 5")
                 (loop for n = (read stream nil nil)
                       while (numberp n)
                       do (vector-push-extend n vector)))
               vector)
#(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for a literal array in Common Lisp like the one you're describing is `#(1 2 3 4 5)`.  You can simply type that instead of `1 2 3 4 5`, and **read** it in:

```
CL-USER> (read)  
; type "#(1 2 3 4 5)" (no quotes)
#(1 2 3 4 5)     ; return value

CL-USER> (let ((array (read)))
           (type-of array))
; type "#(1 2 3)" (no quotes)
(SIMPLE-VECTOR 3)
```